# dynamic batch size with tf.data or tf.contrib.datta

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I can use a placeholder as the batch_size with tf.train.batch_join() (Which is queue based,) so I can dynamically change the batch size in the training loop.

But when I use placeholder (or a nontrainable variable) as the batch_size for tf.data.Dataset.batch(), I got this error,

```
ValueError: Cannot capture a placeholder (name:Placeholder, type:Placeholder) by value.
```

The whole error stack trace is very long. I traced the error to v1.4 tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:108 in make_one_shot_iterator()

```
@function.Defun(capture_by_value=True)
```

Full stack trace attached. I was trying the official tf resnet model.

Thanks!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 281, in <module>
    tf.app.run(argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 270, in main
    hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 708, in _train_model
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 577, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 663, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 269, in <lambda>
    True, FLAGS.data_dir, worker_batch_size, FLAGS.epochs_per_eval),
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 157, in input_fn
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 113, in make_one_shot_iterator
    _make_dataset.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 486, in add_to_graph
    self._create_definition_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 321, in _create_definition_if_needed
    self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 338, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl
    outputs = self._func(*inputs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 111, in _make_dataset
    return self._as_variant_tensor()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1225, in _as_variant_tensor
    self._input_dataset._as_variant_tensor(),  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1036, in _as_variant_tensor
    self._input_dataset._as_variant_tensor(),  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1147, in _as_variant_tensor
    self._input_dataset._as_variant_tensor(),  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1598, in _as_variant_tensor
    output_types=nest.flatten(self.output_types))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1062, in prefetch_dataset
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 691, in create_op
    inputs[i] = self._add_tensor_and_parents(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 706, in _add_tensor_and_parents
    op = self._add_op_and_parents(tensor.op)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 718, in _add_op_and_parents
    "by value." % (op.name, op.type))
ValueError: Cannot capture a placeholder (name:Placeholder, type:Placeholder) by value.
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have to use initializable iterator, not one_shot

Comment: Yes, When I use dataset.make_initializable_iterator() and call iterator.initializer before get_next. I can feed batch_size as placeholder.